# How to display the text content of a vector out of an eventReactive environment?

Tags: r, shiny, lapply

I am trying to get a vector with different character strings to display the combination of abbreviations exaclty like they are appearing in the pie chart at the moment. Everytime I try to display the output of `InputList` an error occurs.

The abbreviations are created through the different input fields for Geography and World Regions. They are then put together with an underscore to get a final character string. These character strings (one for each added row of input) should then be displayed as text/list somewhere.

Here is a MWE of my code:

```
# library(packages,etc.)

GeographyList <- c("Africa","Asia","Europe")
WorldRegionList <- c("Region1", "Region2")

ui <- fluidPage(#....design etc.,

  # this is just a demo to show the input values
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("inputwidgets"),

    actionButton('number', 
                 'Add row'),
    actionButton('delete_number', 
                 'Delete row'),
    actionButton("update", "Update View"),

    h4("allocation"),
    plotOutput("allocation"),
    textOutput("labels"))



)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # (For remove button) Reactive value that is triggered by add and remove button
  reac <- reactiveValues()


  observeEvent(c(input$number,input$delete_number), {
    # you need to add 1 to not start with 0
    add <- input$number+1
    # restriction for delete_number > number
    delete <- if(input$delete_number > input$number) add else input$delete_number
    calc <- add - delete
    reac$calc <- if(calc > 0) 1:calc else 1
  })
  # Get new input by clicking Add Row
  observe({
    req(reac$calc)
    output$inputwidgets = renderUI({
      input_list <- lapply(reac$calc, function(i) {
        Geography <- input[[paste0("Geography",i)]]
        Region <- input[[paste0("WorldRegion",i)]]
        amount <- input[[paste0("amount",i)]]

        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 selectInput(paste0("Geography", i),
                             label = paste0("Geography", i),
                             choices = GeographyList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = if(!is.null(Geography)) Geography)
          ),
          column(3,
                 selectInput(paste0("WorldRegion", i),
                             label = paste0("World Region", i),
                             choices = WorldRegionList,
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             selected = if(!is.null(Region)) Region)),
          column(3, 
                 # Input: Specify the amount ----
                 numericInput(
                   paste0("amount",i),
                   label="Amount",
                   value = if(!is.null(amount)) amount else 0
                 )
          )
        )
      })
      do.call(tagList, input_list)
    })
  })

  InputList <- eventReactive(input$update,{ 
    lapply(1:input$number, function(i) { paste0(
      # desired abbreviations needed to store in a list
      switch(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$Geography",i))),
             "Africa"="Afr_",
             "Asia"="AS_",
             "Europe"="EU_"

             , ignoreNULL=FALSE),

      switch(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$WorldRegion",i))),
             "Region1"="Em",
             "Region2"="Dev"
             ,ignoreNULL=FALSE))
    })

    #InputList <-paste0(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$Geography",i))),eval(parse(text=paste0("input$WorldRegion",i))))
  })

  output$labels <- renderText({ paste0(InputList()) })

  # List with the desired abbreviations, 1 abbreviation for each row



  allocation <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    x <- c(input$amount1, input$amount2, input$amount3)
    lbls <- c(paste0(InputList()))
    pie(x, labels = lbls)
  })
  output$allocation <- renderPlot({
    if (input$update == 0)
      return()

    (allocation())
  })

}
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I try to display `InputList` as simple text the error `Object of type closure is not subsettable`.

Thank you very much. I am beginner at shiny so I would appreciate any kind of help!!

Comment: If the goal is to show the selected combinations as text separate from the pie, then you need a `textOutput("labels")` in `ui` and a `output$labels <- renderText({ paste0(inputList()) })` in `server`. Though I am not sure this is what you need.

Comment: Hm. It works for me. Where do you add the render text statement?

Comment: @teofil Sorry, it works for me as well however only for one row. So when I add another row, I need two character strings, one for each row. Right now it only displays one. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Not sure what is happening on your end. But it seems to for with multiple rows for me too. Unless I am missing the point. https://paste.pics/6ad82f6379f2370bdc8cd066a46543bc

Comment: Ah it might be because my real code is slightly more complicated. I also have a remove-row button for which the code is a bit more extensive - could that be the problem? I whave updated the code in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @teofil s debugging help, I have figured it out. 
Instead of using `input$number` I use `tail(reac$calc, n=1)` to access the last value of `reac$calc` (i.e. the number of input rows displayed).

Here is the code in case anyone else experiences a similar problem:

```
 InputList <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    lapply(1:tail(reac$calc, n=1), function(i) {
      paste0(# desired abbreviations needed to store in a list
        switch(
          eval(parse(text = paste0(
            "input$Geography", i
          ))),
          "Africa" = "Afr_",
          "Asia" = "AS_",
          "Europe" = "EU_",
          ignoreNULL = FALSE
        ),
        switch(
          eval(parse(text = paste0(
            "input$WorldRegion", i
          ))),
          "Region1" = "Em",
          "Region2" = "Dev",
          ignoreNULL = FALSE
        ))
    })
  })
```

Now, all character strings are being displayed!

Comment: Great that you worked it out. I think you can accept your own answer and close the thread.

Comment: Yes thank you! Unfortunately it tells me that I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer but I will do it in 2 days then!

Answer (score 1):

When your app starts, `input$number` has value `0`, so your `lapply` generating `lbls` has nothing to cycle over. Once you click `add`, things work. Except, you have one more input UI than the labels created, because you start with a UI, but its index is 0, so at UI5 you have index 4, and you are generating 4 instead of 5 labels.

I added a couple of `cat` calls to aid with debugging. See the two code chunks below.

First to check the value of the `add` action button.

```
  InputList <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    cat("The value of input$number is: ", input$number, "\n\n")
    lapply(1:input$number, function(i) {
      paste0(# desired abbreviations needed to store in a list
        switch(
          eval(parse(text = paste0(
            "input$Geography", i
          ))),
          "Africa" = "Afr_",
          "Asia" = "AS_",
          "Europe" = "EU_",
          ignoreNULL = FALSE
        ),
        switch(
          eval(parse(text = paste0(
            "input$WorldRegion", i
          ))),
          "Region1" = "Em",
          "Region2" = "Dev",
          ignoreNULL = FALSE
        ))
    })
    #InputList <-paste0(eval(parse(text=paste0("input$Geography",i))),eval(parse(text=paste0("input$WorldRegion",i))))
  })
```

Then to check the contents of `lbls`.

```
  allocation <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    x <- c(input$amount1, input$amount2, input$amount3)
    lbls <- c(paste0(InputList()))
    cat("The created labels are", lbls, "\n\n")
    pie(x, labels = lbls)
  })
```

And here is the console output when you run the app:

1. When you haven't added a row, but you click update:

[image]

2. When you click add once and click update (Geography 2 is generated):

[image]

3. When you have added 4 rows and click update (Geography 5 is generated):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually figured it out this way! It was fairly simple, I posted my answer as well.